# C, Why is my 'px' variable zero?

Tags: c, arduino, avr

Ok, the bug is strange and I have no idea what's going on.
I'm running my code on an at90usb1286.

Here's the problematic code:

```
        uint16_t r = rand();
        t1 = r;

        px = r%52;
        t2 = px;

        py = r%28;
        t3 = py;

        px = px * 6;
        t4 = px;

        py = py * 8;
        t5 = py;

        py += 8;
```

**Context:**

The t# variables are temporary variables I am using to debug this...
They are displayed on a connected display. px and py are just global uint16_ts.

**The Bug:**

All t# variables except t4 display sensible values, but t4 remains 0 no matter what value is displayed for t2.

Why!!!?

It's been screwing with my mind for hours! :'(

Thanks for any advice! :)
I know this probably isn't a good way to use random's though :P

(I've tagged arduino as I suspect it may be similar)

Rest of the code:
(I have tried with the global vars non-static aswell)

```
#include "util/cli.h"
#include "drivers/lcd/syscalls.h"
#include "drivers/input/syscalls.h"
#include "drivers/led/syscalls.h"
#include "drivers/scheduler/syscalls.h"
#include <util/delay.h>

static int x = 0, y = 0;

static int px;
static int py; /*Pickup*/

static uint16_t score = 0;

static uint8_t dir; /*0 -> NESW <- 3*/

static uint16_t t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;

void render_thread() {
    lcd_clear_screen();

    while(1) {
        cli();
        lcd_display_char_xy(' ', x, y);
        if(dir & 0x01)
            y -= 8;

        if(dir & 0x02)
            x += 6;

        if(dir & 0x04)
            y += 8;

        if(dir & 0x08)
            x -= 6;

        if(x < 0)
            x = 0;
        if(y < 8)
            y = 8;
        if(x > 312)
            x = 312;
        if(y > 232)
            y = 232;

        lcd_display_char_xy('.', px, py);
        lcd_display_char_xy('@', x, y);
        /*Display score*/
        lcd_display_move(0, 0);
        lcd_display_hex(&score, 2);

        /*Display test variables*/
        lcd_display_move(60, 0);
        lcd_display_hex(&t1, 2);
        lcd_display_move(100, 0);
        lcd_display_hex(&t2, 2);
        lcd_display_move(140, 0);
        lcd_display_hex(&t3, 2);
        lcd_display_move(180, 0);
        lcd_display_hex(&t4, 2);
        lcd_display_move(220, 0);
        lcd_display_hex(&t5, 2);
        sei();
        _delay_ms(16);
    }
}

void game_thread() {
    px = 24;
    py = 32;

    while(1) {
        cli();
        if(px == x && py == y) {
            uint16_t r = rand();
            t1 = r;

            px = r%52;
            t2 = px;

            py = r%28;
            t3 = py;

            px = px * 6;
            t4 = px;

            py = py * 8;
            t5 = py;

            py += 8;
            score++;
        }
        sei();
        scheduler_switch();
    }
}

void user_thread() {
    while(1) {
        if(switch_north())
            dir |= 1;
        else
            dir &= 0x0E;

        if(switch_east())
            dir |= 1<<1;
        else
            dir &= 0x0D;

        if(switch_south())
            dir |= 1<<2;
        else
            dir &= 0x0B;

        if(switch_west())
            dir |= 1<<3;
        else
            dir &= 0x07;

        scheduler_switch();
    }
}

void cli_start() {
    Task* game_task = scheduler_create_task(game_thread, 128);
    scheduler_submit_task(game_task);

    Task* render_task = scheduler_create_task(render_thread, 128);
    scheduler_submit_task(render_task);

    Task* user_task = scheduler_create_task(user_thread, 128);
    scheduler_submit_task(user_task);
}
```

Comment: so, basically you want to say that `(rand()%52)*6` is always 0?

Comment: How are the `t#` variables declared ?

Comment: Can you show the full code, please? Also provide all of the values involved.

Comment: Did you call `srand`? It may be that, in your implementation, the unseeded `rand` produces a number divisible by `52`. What does `rand` return?

Comment: Voting to close if no requested information is provided.

Comment: yes ((rand()%52)*6 is always zero

Comment: @Stepperz69 Then tell us what rand() returns

Comment: @nos for example running it a few times is giving me random values 0x2CD9, 0x0C2A, 0x3782, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial value of `rand()` is probably divisable by 52 (as suggested by Lashane).  First of all try to make sure you call `srand()` if you are using -- BUT do make sure you are calling it exactly and only ONCE.  For simple applications you can use the `time()` value for seeding into `srand`, however for more secure applications you should find something to seed with that cannot easily be guessed.

You always have the risk of the value be divisable by 52, so if zero is an undesirable values use

```
px = (r%51)+1;
```

to make sure that the values returned are between 1 and 51

Comment: Thanks for the advice, as you can see from my comment above, the values returned by rand() are perfectly fine. The modulo is also producing good values. It's only when I multiply it where it becomes zero. That is it always becomes zero, no matter the result of th modulo.

Comment: I don't know what complier you are using, but I would start looking into any known (1) compiler issues,  (2) different optimization levels, and (3) looking at the assembler that is created -- and use whatever debugger you have available to single step through the code.

Comment: Yeah, I think the compiler may be doing something stupid here... :/ I'll look into it.

Comment: Make sure sizeof int is what you think it is, at least witth gcc, there's compiler options to make an int 8 bits on AVR processors albeit you should also look closely at (all) the code for any buffer overflows, you could move the declaration of px around to try to see if any buffer overflows affet it.

Comment: Look at the addresses 19A and 1BC, game_thread() seems to be in two places... What also looks odd is that 21C seems to rely on 1BC for the value in r15. Is this sort of odd setup normal? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JCelPzi7Z6Vd8mO5Qxr--TmQEpcEsM98wNxVBXvjA9I

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 3 threads, BUT YOU ARE NOT TAKING CARE ABOUT WRITE MEMORY COLLISIONS.

Two threads are using px: **game_thread** and **render_thread**, maybe **lcd_display_char_xy** in render_thread takes px referenced, and modifies it in a unspected time.

I suggest you try using a "**int pxg**" for exclusive use of game_thread and other "**int pxr**" for exclusive use in render_thread (and remove int px). It must solve the problem.

Or, just for test, you could comment **lcd_display_char_xy('.', px, py);**, and px in game_thread must work in expected way.

Comment: Bearing in mind that I wrote the scheduler and I disable interrupts when i access the variables. I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: And no, commenting lcd_display_char_xy('.', px, py); doesn't work... :(

Comment: and int pxg y int pxr test?

Comment: There are no write collisions. Interrupts are disabled so a task switch cannot happen.

Comment: This is on a single core 8-bit microcontroller btw :P

Answer (score 0):

Well it seemed to be an optimisation issue. I was initially using the optimisation flag **-Os** and after changing it to **-O3** or **-Ofast** it seemed to run perfectly :)

I don't know what on earth was going on with the size optimised code but it appeared that the compiler had split the game_thread code into a couple of jumbled pieces...

Thanks for the help everyone! :D